# I am getting PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am not able to connect to MYSQL with nodejs even though I can access MySQL with Workbench. I am getting the PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR error and I am not able to determine anything wrong with the code here. How should I go about it? Many thanks in advance.

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mysql = require('mysql')

const app = express()


const SELECT_ALL_PRODUCT_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM products';

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'password',
    database:'reactdb'
})


app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world from the product server')
})

app.get('/productlist', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCT_QUERY, (err, results) => {
      if(err){
          return res.send(err)
      }
      else {
          return res.json({
              data: results
          })
      }
  })
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Product server is listening to port 4000')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the connection error by creating a new MySQL user instead of using the root user. Thanks